# Can't find services package.json when running docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, nestjs

I am building a `docker-compose.yml` file inside a workspace, but when I try to run docker-compose, I can't start my services because of the following error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/entity-service/package.json'` the same error happens when trying to start the agent-portal-service container as well but the error happens in this directory `/agent-portal-service/package.json`. But my projects indeed have a package.json file, I think that this is related to the context that docker-compose is running.

Here is my workspace structure:

```
├── agent-portal-service
├── data
├── docker-compose.yml
└── entity-service
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  agent_portal_service:
    working_dir: /agent-portal-service
    container_name: agent_portal_service
    image: node:16
    volumes:
      - /agent-workspace:/agent-portal-service
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    command: npm run start:debug
    tty: true

  entity_service:
    working_dir: /entity-service
    container_name: entity_service
    image: node:16
    volumes:
      - /agent-workspace:/entity-service
    ports:
      - 3101:3101
    command: npm run start:debug
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    command: mongod --port 27017
    restart: always
```

I am expecting to be able to run the `agent_portal_service` and `entity_service` containers successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important parts of your entity-service definition look like this

```
  entity_service:
    working_dir: /entity-service
    volumes:
      - /agent-workspace:/entity-service
    command: npm run start:debug
```

You map `/agent-workspace` to `/entity-service` in the volumes section. You also set your working directory to `/entity-service`. In effect, your working directory is `/agent-workspace` on your host machine. There's no `package.json` file in the `/agent-workspace` directory, so your `npm` command fails.

To fix it, I'd map `/agent-workspace/entity-service` to `/entity-service` instead. That way, you'll have a package.json file in your `/entity-service` directory inside the container.

Like this

```
volumes:
  - /agent-workspace/entity-service:/entity-service
```